# `Error response from daemon: No command specified` How to solve this?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I got the error in the title while doing docker compose. The error messages is very vague.. I don't know what is wrong

My docker file

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
WORKDIR /application

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        gcc \
        libc-dev \
        linux-headers \
        bash; \
    pip install -r requirements.txt;

COPY . /application


EXPOSE 5000
VOLUME /application
CMD gunicorn --workers=1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 application:application
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}

services:
  webapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      network: host
    container_name: webapp 
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./:/application
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
```

When I do

```
prometheus_exercise$ docker compose up --build
[+] Building 31.5s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                      
 => [webapp internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                         0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 357B                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                            0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine                                                                         1.9s
 => [webapp 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-alpine@sha256:2e94e493d6d5010d739ea473e44ea40f7c6e168bcb78e0c5a48c64f06aafbf5f                   0.0s
 => [webapp internal] load build context                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.75kB                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 2/5] WORKDIR /application                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [webapp 3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt                                                                                    0.0s
 => [webapp 4/5] RUN apk add --no-cache   gcc   libc-dev   linux-headers   bash;  pip install -r requirements.txt;                                 28.0s
 => [webapp 5/5] COPY . /application                                                                                                                0.1s
 => [webapp] exporting to image                                                                                                                     1.3s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                             1.2s 
 => => writing image sha256:1b86856b6f184dbea97fb2164784cff206b11469fc339b035e1d6d103393dc45                                                        0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/prometheus_exercise-webapp                                                                                       0.0s 
[+] Running 0/0                                                                                                                                          
 ⠋ Container webapp  Creating                                                                                                                       0.0s 
Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

The first time I run it it said

```
[+] Running 2/2                                                                                                                                          
 ✔ Network prometheus_exercise_default           Created                                                                                            0.1s 
 ✔ Volume "prometheus_exercise_prometheus_data"  Created                                                                                            0.0s 
 ⠋ Container webapp                              Creating                                                                                           0.0s 
 ⠋ Container prometheus                          Creating                                                                                           0.0s 
Error response from daemon: No command specified
```

But now it is just No command specified after webapp...

How can I solve and what is the reason of the error?

EDIT: Reading some other answers it seems that webapp does not have a command -which is weird because *it is right there* in the dockerfile

Anyways I added

```
command: 
      - gunicorn --workers=1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 application:application'
```

And now the error disappears! but then another error!

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd application && gunicorn --workers=1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 application:application'\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

what to do?

EDIT2:
I changed the yaml file into

```
command:  'gunicorn --workers=1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 application:application'
```

and now it runs but fails

```
 ✔ Container webapp      Recreated                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 ✔ Container prometheus  Running                                                                                                                    0.0s 
Attaching to prometheus, webapp
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
webapp      | Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'application'.
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [6] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6)
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
webapp      | [2023-07-02 14:08:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
webapp exited with code 4
```

The `application.py` file is

```
from app.flask_app import create_app

application = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

Where the application is on another file `flask_app.py` in the app directory

```
import prometheus_client
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.middleware.dispatcher import DispatcherMiddleware


def index():
    return 'home'


def create_app():
    main_app = Flask(__name__)
    main_app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)

    # Add prometheus wsgi middleware to route /metrics requests
    app = DispatcherMiddleware(main_app.wsgi_app, {
        '/metrics': prometheus_client.make_wsgi_app()
    })

    return app
```

Comment: The `docker-compose up --build` output suggests it's not seeing the last three lines of the Dockerfile for some reason.  Is there anything unusual about the file?

Comment: For a multi-word `command:` override, you'd need to either put the command on the same line as the directive `command: gunicorn ... application:application` or make each shell word be a separate list item; that's what leads to the final error you show.

Comment: @DavidMaze  how can I discover if the file is unusual. I also notice that the build seems to finish at copy application and ignores the rest

Comment: Does it have unusual line endings of some sort; weird Unicode white space; an unsaved copy in your editor?